# How to make the tufte-handout document class use Computer Modern typefaces

Tags: tufte, typefaces

In the documentation for the [tufte-handout](https://github.com/Tufte-LaTeX/tufte-latex) document class (specifically in the file sample-handout.tex), I see the following statement:

[image]

> If the Palatino, Helvetica, and Bera Mono typefaces are installed, this
> style will use them automatically. Otherwise, we'll fall back on the
> Computer Modern typefaces.

I do have the Palatino, Helvetica, and Bera Mono typefaces installed, but I would like to see how my document looks using the Computer Modern typefaces.

**Question:**  How do I **force** the tufte-handout document class to use the Computer Modern typefaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class appears to have a `[nofonts]` option to stop it trying to load additional fonts

Comment: Thank you! I changed the line `\documentclass[justified]{tufte-handout}` to `\documentclass[nofonts, justified]{tufte-handout}` and it worked.